# how to solve "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting

I have created a web application in MVC 4 and host it in local IIS and it is working fine but when I am hosting it in 3rd party server i.e. Glob-host then it is give me error and my application is not running. Please any one give me suggestion for this what is the wrong in my application.
Error is...

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Most common points to consider:

→ You will have to make sure to reference to all DLLs, rebuild the project and re-upload on server.

→ Make sure that 32 bit application support is enabled for the application pool which is being used by your site in production server. (If any DLL requires 32 bit support and you have not enabled it, you will face such issue)